# How can I remove / delete specific weights below a threshold value from a neural network layer (dense layer or convolution layer) in Keras?

Tags: keras

I have a neural network model in Keras which is trained on a dataset. Now, I would like to remove / delete some specific weights from Dense layers and Convolution layers. Is there a way to do that in Keras ? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: In other way, I densely connections will transform into sparse connections

Comment: Do you want to do this after the model is trained?

Comment: @sdcbr Hi, please check my reply below after your suggested solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `get_weights` and `set_weights` Layer methods. I will illustrate the principle for a toy model with one dense layer:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

x = np.random.rand(10,10)
y = np.random.rand(10,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1, input_shape=(10, )))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(x, y)
```

The weights for our layer consist of two numpy arrays, for the weights and the bias respectively:

```
weights = model.get_layer(index=-1).get_weights()
weights

[array([[ 0.51373583],
        [-0.64512885],
        [ 0.41436252],
        [-0.5230512 ],
        [-0.7272273 ],
        [ 0.17996567],
        [-0.63398594],
        [ 0.3416807 ],
        [ 0.66054064],
        [-0.11221145]], dtype=float32), array([0.01157765], dtype=float32)]
```

To 'remove' weights that are under a certain threshold, you can modify the weight arrays. For instance, to set all negative weights to zero:

```
sparsified_weights = []
threshold = 0.

for w in weights:
    bool_mask = (w > threshold).astype(int)
    sparsified_weights.append(w*bool_mask)
```

You can then set these weights on the layer with `set_weights()`:

```
model.get_layer(index=-1).set_weights(sparsified_weights)
```

Verify this by calling `get_weights()` again.

Comment: Thanks @sdcbr but problem was not resolved. Actually, the solution suggested by you solves the problem partially. Let me explain how. My intention is to completely remove the weight-edge (weight-connection) from the neural network if the value of weight is under threshold. So, when all such weight connections are removed from neural network (say dense layer), a network with sparse layer is resulted. And so, the network size reduced. 
But using your solution, I can reduce below-threshold weights to zero. But when I retrain model using these new weights, again the ZERO weights get some value

Comment: Therefore, I intend to remove weights from network permanently, such that when I retrain the model, the gradients are not calculated for the removed weights. (since a absent weight will not contribute to gradient). Is the issue clear @sdcbr?

Comment: I agree with Aakash, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: I had the same question and it made me sad that the answer didn't answer my question. Definitely not personal!